# Raspberry Pi4 uhubctl bash script wont run

Tags: bash

Writing a bash script to turn on and off the USB ports on a raspberry pi 4. Using uhubctl.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to turn on and off power to usb port
# Uses uhubctl
#
time_w=5
#cd uhubctl
uhubctl -a off -l 1-1
#
sleep "$time_w"
#
uhubctl -a on -l 1-1
#
echo "All done"
```

I can run this `sudo uhubctl -a off -l 1-1` from the command line without issue.

But if I run the script with `sudo bash USB_Power.sh` I get the following error.

```
!o compatible smart hubs detected at location 1-1
Run with -h to get usage info.
All done
```

Comment: And you have checked that it is compatible?

Comment: @Mats Karlsson Im using just the onboard raspberry pi ports.

Comment: Thats was not what I asked!

Comment: On the command line do you run it as Pi or as root (`sudo`)?  Also what happens if you just run `sudo USB_Power.sh`?  Is this the only version of the script on your system?

Comment: @Andyroo I run the commands as `sudo` and I also run the script as `sudo` This is the only version of the script on the system. When I run the command is executes just fine - but when I run it as the script it just doesn't work.

Comment: @MatsKarlsson Raspberry Pi 4 is supported. I am using the onboard usb ports. Specifically the 2.0 ports.

Comment: Do you get the same error without the bash part of the command? Did you add the USB permissions as per https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl#raspberry-pi-4b - does the command work  outside the script?  This is not the same as not reporting an error?

Comment: @Andyroo I am not sure what you mean without the bash part of the command, do you mean running it as an executable or with `sh` either way it wont run. I have been trying to add USB permissions so that I dont have to use sudo - followed the guide still have to use sudo. The command works outside of the script if I use sudo. I am running the command with sudo so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Make the tile executable `sudo chmod +x USB_Power.sh` then run it as `./USB_Power.sh` and `sudo ./USB_Power.sh`

Comment: @Andyroo I made it executable, but I cant run it still from the directory the script is in. when I run `sudo ./USB_Power.sh` I get the following error `sudo: unable to execute ./USB_Power.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you give it different name?  What happens if you `ls USB*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116697/discussion-between-andyroo-and-shekelsbot).

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/118656/edit) your question and correct the command to `sudo uhubctl -a off -l 1-1`? It is still confusing me if it isn't written there.

Comment: @Ingo my bad I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing this script in Microsft Visual Studio Code. I forgot that spaces are interperated differently between Windows and Unix when running Bash. So I changed the document settings in Notepad++ to be Unix, re wrote the code and then it runs fine now.

Still have to use `sudo` because the permissions are not working but not it runs correctly.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-and-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
#!/bin/bash
uhubctl -a off -l 1-1
sleep 5
uhubctl -a on -l 1-1
echo "All done"
```

Answer (score 2):

[uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) author here.

To configure udev USB permissions, simply follow [uhubctl README](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl#linux-usb-permissions).
In particular, for Raspberry Pi 4B, you need to add these 2 lines to file `/etc/udev/rules.d/52-usb.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2109", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", MODE="0666"
```

then either reboot or run this command to apply changes live:

```
sudo udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=usb
```

Note that you do not need to write any scripts to automate your task. Your script is exactly equivalent to this command:

```
uhubctl -l 1-1 -a cycle -d 5
```

Comment: Thank you this helped fix my other issue.

As for the script - I was just needing it to test to see why it wasn't running. The future plan is it needs to mount and unmount a drive as well as transfer a set of specified video files from the camera - but the camera needs to be mounted and not have any power from the usb in order to record. However the command provided could be useful later.

Comment: You cannot have camera mounted and not have any power

Comment: Correct. The script is meant to un-mount the drive and cut power. Then turn on power and mount the drive. And then transfer files. I cant have it being a mounted drive or receive power when its recording because it turns into a USB and defaults to charging. (Or when its done) Unless you have a different idea I should pursue?